# Windows 7 Power Outage: WMC Graceful Blind Shutdown

Tags: shutdown, power, windows-media-center, ups

Problem: Can't shutdown Win7 (blind TV monitor) after power outage while on UPS because WMC won't auto shutdown without mouse clicks on Win7 shutdown screen.

How can I shutdown Win7 without putting power hungry TV monitor on UPS?

Comment: Setting the default action of the power button to shutdown is what I'd try.

Comment: It won't accept Win/x, u, u ?

Comment: so are you saying that you have apps that refuse the shutdown signal from windows for so long that the UPS powers off before the PC does?